# VBA how to set column values to end at a range

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to set multiple columns different values but only until the last row of the first column:

```
Sub Macro7()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'
        Dim rng As Range

        For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            rng.Value = NumberOnly(rng.Value)

        Columns("E:rng").Value = 6
        Columns("D:rng").Value = 8.5

        Next


End Sub
```

I get the message:

> Compile error: Sub or Function not defined

highlighting the `NumberOnly` part of the code

Comment: Is the error not self-explanatory? NumberOnly does not refer to any method within the object library or anything so this should be your own function you are invoking. However, the error tells you it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
   Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

  lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  sh.Range("D" & lastRow + 1 ).value = 8.5
  sh.Range("E" & lastRow + 1).value = 6
```

If you need to add another value on the same column, you can define again the `lastRow` variable, or count the values you add and use `lastRow + k`, k being your number of added values on the same column.

Comment: The values seem to only appear in the last row?

Comment: Good, but if it answered your question, voting the answer up will not kill anybody... :-)